# Duplicate textfield widgets in the KiviMD dialog

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Why when clicking change password button opens a dialog with duplicate textfield widgets?
The code I wrote entirely in .py codes works fine but was not clear. That's why I transcribed it into .kv language.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXrKA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demo2.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.button  import MDFillRoundFlatButton,MDIconButton ,MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


PASSWORD = ["admin"]

class Content(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    

class UserScreen(Screen):
    pass

class DataScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):

    id = {}

    # def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    #     super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
    #     Manager.id["password"] = self.children[0].children[2]
    #     print(ChangePasswordScreen.x)

    def click(self):
        
        if Manager.id["password"].text == PASSWORD[0]:
            Manager.id["password"].text = ""
            self.current = "data_screen"
            self.transition.direction = "up"
        else:
            Manager.id["password"].text = ""
            print("špatné heslo")
    
    def show_change_password(self):

        print()

    
        
        self.dialog = MDDialog(
            title="Change password",
            type="custom",
            content_cls=Content(),  
            buttons=[
                MDFlatButton(
                    text="CANCEL",
                    theme_text_color="Custom",
                    # text_color=DemoApp.styl.primary_color,
                ),
                MDFlatButton(
                    text="OK",
                    theme_text_color="Custom",
                    # text_color=DemoApp.styl.primary_color,
                ),
            ],
        )
        
        self.dialog.open()

        

        # self.dialog.buttons[1].on_press = self.change_password
        self.dialog.buttons[0].on_press = self.dialog.dismiss
        

class Demo2App(MDApp):
    styl = None
    def build(self):
        
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        self.theme_cls.accent_palette = "Green"
        self.styl = self.theme_cls
        Builder.load_file("demo2.kv")
        
Demo2App().run()
```

demo2.kv

```
<Content>:
    id: mywidget
    orientation:"vertical"
    spacing:"12dp"
    size_hint_y:None
    height:"200dp"
    MDTextField:
        hint_text:"current password "
        password:True
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.6}
        size_hint_x:None
        width:200
        focus:True
    MDTextField:
        hint_text:"New password"
        password:True
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.6}
        size_hint_x:None
        width:200
    MDTextField:
        hint_text:"Check new password "
        password:True
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.6}
        size_hint_x:None
        width:200


Manager: 
    UserScreen:
        name: "user_screen"
        MDLabel:
            id:user_title
            text:"Přihlášení do databáze"
            font_style:"H4"
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.8}
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 500
            halign:"center"
            theme_text_color:"Secondary"
        MDTextField:
            id: password
            hint_text:"Password"
            password:True
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.6}
            size_hint_x:None
            width:200
            focus:True
        MDFlatButton:
            text:"Change password "
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.55}
            font_size:11
            on_press: root.show_change_password()
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text:"Entry"
            pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.4}
            on_press:root.click()
    DataScreen:
        name: "data_screen"
```

Comment: There may be an issue of your `kv` getting loaded twice. Since your `kv` file is named `demo2.kv`, it will get loaded automatically by Kivy. Plus you are loading it explicitly in the line `Builder.load_file("demo2.kv")`. Try just removing that line of code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).